# SharePoint Framework v1.1.0 requirement

Tags: 2016, spfx, nodejs, gulp

I want to build my first spfx page on our SP2016 on-premise environment. Could you advice what is the requirement? I mentioned v1.1.0 because later version are not supported by SP2016 according to [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support). However there is no further explanation on how to setup SP2016 dev environment.

May I know, which version I required?

- NodeJS
- Yeoman
- Gulp
- NPM
- SharePoint yeoman generator

Another question, why Microsoft make on-premise administrator so frustrated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are limited on Framwerk version (1.1.0) instead of this list of tools.

Check this link:

https://github.com/smukked/generator-sp-classic

Found via https://yeoman.io/generators/ and looking for "sharepoint". Actually I've not tried to use it.

I think you'll can create developments using this Yeoman Generator like the "yo @microsoft/sharepoint" used in Docs Examples.

Comment: Before I can run "Yo" I need to install NodeJS first but I read some blog saying I need to use v6.x and some say v8.x. Same for each of the package gulp. Different type of error prompt up, etc.. so I need a working version combination to isolate my problem.

Comment: Node 6.x was the one who coexisted with SPFx 1.1.0 in time. 
Node 8.x needs to be slightly tuned to work with 1.1.0 --> 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#spfx-development-for-sharepoint-server-2016 
Yeoman works from Node 6.x, npm comes bundled in node, using npm install --global gulp-cli should install the correct gulp version (2.0.1 should be fine). 
Hope this helps

Comment: I am using node v6.11.2, which Yo version I should use?

Comment: The current version should work.
Installing via npm install -g yo should get a compatible version
Check --> https://yeoman.io/learning/

Comment: I tried many times (install/uninstall/delete the folder,etc) all lead to same error:
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@3.1.0 postinstall script 'yodoctor'. Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

Comment: Have yo tried to update all and tune Node to HTTP1 as mentioned in article?
 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/yo  <-- Here you will find the older versions. I don't know exactly which works with Node 6x, it was released around 2016, I supose Yo versions from then should work.
Node 6.11.2 was released on 2017-08-01.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99909/discussion-between-biggum-and-mark-l).